# How do I access localhost ports on a virtual pc?

Tags: localhost, virtual-pc

I've downloaded and installed the Microsoft Virtual PC and Windows XP mode image for testing IE6. I have several projects on localhost that I access by port numbers in my vhosts file, for example:

```
Listen *:82
<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/htdocs/project-folder/public/"
</VirtualHost>
```

In the virtual machine I have changed the hosts file so that `http://mymachine` redirects to my root localhost directory (equivalent to `http://localhost:80/`).

How do I set up the virtual machine so that `http://project-n/` goes to the correct localhost port? And sadly, `http://mymachine:82/` doesn't do the job =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the virtual computer, in the hosts file I have added

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx      project-n.dev
```

where the x's are my host computer's ip address.

In my host computers httpd-vhosts.conf file I changed the *:80 port to localhost:80. I don't know why this works, just that it does.

My httpd-vhosts.conf file now looks like:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    DocumentRoot "path/to/htdocs/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot path/to/htdocs/project-a/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:82>
    DocumentRoot path/to/htdocs/project-b/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, in the virtual pc, when I goto 'http://project-n:81/' it will load project-a, and'http://project-n:82' loads project-b/public =D

Comment: Shouldn't `http://mymachine:81` be `http://project-n.dev:81`? If not, what's that for?

Comment: It should be. You are correct, sir. I shall correct my answer

Comment: The hosts file is usually located at C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows XP.